# S3 - Routing for multiple React application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, deployment, react-router

I am deploy 3 React applications using S3. I am facing a routing problem which I am explaining through an example.

Lets assume the three applications are 
1. A login Portal
2. Driver portal
3. Passenger Portal

The login portal is common for both driver and passenger. Once we login as a driver it will direct to Driver Portal. Similarly for passenger portal too login works.

I am using JWT token based on which I am validating the client side routing using React Router. This works locally fine if I have three dev server each for the apps. I am able to redirect from one server to the other.
For example if I run my login at port 3001 and passenger at 3002, On successful login just redirecting it to 'localhost:3002/passenger/:passengerId'

I am trying to deploy statically by generating three folders.

The three three folders is having routes like 
1. "/login"
2. "/passenger"
3. "/driver"

The problem I am facing is I am not able to navigate by using the address bar for nested route. For example if I want to access "/passenger/:passengerId", it throws no page found since it is just a static deployment.

I need a solution where I can Hit directly any nested route. This I guess can be done by providing any kind of fallback if we have a nested route starting with "/passenger/***" to fallback to the index.html inside the passenger folder.

I am not exactly sure how this can be done. Or even if there is a different approach by which I can deploy it would be helpful.

Comment: Are you familiar with hash URLs?

Comment: yes. I am familiar